# @Cacheable not working, still calling the caching method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-test

I am trying to use @Cacheable to cache the roles regardless of the parameter. But the @Cacheable does not quite work and the method would get called twice.

CachingConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(@Value("${caching.ttl.period}") long period,
                                     @Value("${caching.ttl.unit}") String unit) {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager() {
            @Override
            public Cache createConcurrentMapCache(String name) {
                return new ConcurrentMapCache(name, CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                        .expireAfterWrite(period, TimeUnit.valueOf(unit)).build().asMap(), true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

RoleMappingService:

```
@Service
public class RoleMappingService {
private final AdminClient adminClient;

    public RoleMappingService(AdminClient adminClient) {
        this.adminClient = adminClient;
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "allRoles", key = "#root.method")
    public List<Role> getAllRoles(String sessionToken) {
        AdminSession adminSession = new AdminSession();
        AdminSession.setSessionToken(sessionToken);

        List<RoleGroup> allRoleGroups = this.adminClient.getAllRoleGroups(adminSession)
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList());

        List<Role> allRoles = allRoleGroups
                .stream()
                .map(RoleGroup::getRoles)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return allRoles;
    }
```

Test:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

public class RoleCachingTest {

    private final JFixture fixture = new JFixture();

    private AdminClient adminClient = mock(AdminClient.class);

    @Test
    public void allRolesShouldBeCached(){
        RoleGroup mockRoleGroup = mock(RoleGroup.class);
        Role mockRole = this.fixture.create(Role.class);

        when(this.adminClient.getAllRoleGroups(any(AdminSession.class)))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(Arrays.asList(mockRoleGroup)));

        when(mockRoleGroup.getRoles()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(mockRole));

        RoleMappingService sut = new RoleMappingService(adminClient);

        List<Role> firstRes = sut.getAllRoles(
                fixture.create(String.class));

        List<Role> secondRes = sut.getAllRoles(
                fixture.create(String.class));
        assertEquals(firstRes.size(), secondRes.size());
        assertEquals(firstRes.get(0).getId(), secondRes.get(0).getId());
        assertEquals(firstRes.get(0).getRoleName(), secondRes.get(0).getRoleName());

        // The getAllRoleGroups() should not be called on the second call
        verify(this.adminClient, times(1)).getAllRoleGroups(any(AdminSession.class));

    }
```

The adminClient.getAllRoleGroups() would always get called twice in this test, while I expect it would only get called once because of @Cacheable.

The project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4cEY.png)

Comment: The @Cachable annotation is processed by the Spring dependency injection. However, you build your test target by yourself (via a mock) and don't request it from Spring. For example, add: `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to the test class and `@Autowire private AdminClient adminClient` so Spring builds and injects your class with a cache.

Comment: @cruftex
That makes sense. But I would get a NullPointer exception for adminClient by following these steps. I also tried '@ExtendWith' (Junit5), and got a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'proxy.AdminClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I could not found a workaround yet, my AdminClient is annotated with Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your @Cacheable annotation is not working because you have not specified Interface for class. This is because of proxy created for caching by Spring. Spring has specified below in its documentation . I thing you have not specified proxy-target-class, it means it will be default to false. If it is false it will use JDK interface based proxies. But in your case you class i.e. RollMappingService is not implementing interface. Create interface RollMappingService with method getAllRoles and implement it, will sole your problem.

> Controls what type of caching proxies are created for classes annotated with the @Cacheable or @CacheEvict annotations. If the proxy-target-class attribute is set to true, then class-based proxies are created. If proxy-target-class is false or if the attribute is omitted, then standard JDK interface-based proxies are created. (See Section 9.6, “Proxying mechanisms” for a detailed examination of the different proxy types.)

Also modify your test class to create Spring bean for RoleMappingService in following ways and inject mock of AdminClient into it

```
 @Mock
private AdminClient mockedAdminClient;

@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private RoleMappingService roleMappingService

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(roleMappingService, 
    "adminClient",
            mockedAdminClient);
}
```

Comment: Did not quite work, I added an interface called RoleMapping with method getAllRoles (without annotation in here). Then I implement this interface in the RoleMappingService and added an Override annotation on method getAllRoles. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: One more thing I found is that, you are not using RoleMappingService as spring bean but creating using new . You should create RoleMappingService as spring bean and then you can inject mock instance of adminClient using ReflectionUtil to spring bean RoleMappingService. Please let me know if it works

Comment: yes. This was the case! Thank you for replying.

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. What about static function testing on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69392493/unit-test-for-static-functions-in-java/69392827?noredirect=1#comment122652187_69392827) page?

Comment: Thanks for voting. I checked you link and I think here, there is no need to mock static method. Although static method can be mocked with powerMockito.