# Java / Spring: Cannot test Caching in Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

In my Java application I am trying to test the following service method with a Unit Test:

```
@Service
@EnableCaching
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LabelServiceImpl implements LabelService {

    private static final String CACHE_NAME = "demoCache";

    private final LabelRepository labelRepository;


    @Override
    public List<LabelDTO> findByUuid(UUID uuid) {
        final Label label = labelRepository.findByUuid(uuid)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Not found."));
        final List<LabelDTO> labelList = labelRepository.findByUuid(uuid);
        return labelList;
    }
}
```

Here is my Unit Test:

```
@Import({CacheConfig.class, LabelServiceImpl.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableCaching
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = {
        CacheAutoConfiguration.class,
        RedisAutoConfiguration.class
})
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CachingTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private LabelServiceImpl labelService;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;


    @Mock
    private LabelRepository labelRepository;


    @Test
    void givenRedisCaching_whenFindUuid_thenReturnFromCache() {

        //code omitted 
        
        LabelDTO labelFromDb = labelService.findByUuid(uuid);
        LabelDTO labelFromCache = labelService.findByUuid(uuid);
        verify(labelRepository, times(1)).findByUuid(uuid);
    }
}
```

When I use `@Autowired` for `LabelServiceImpl` in the Unit Test, I get "*Nullpointer exception*" error. If I use `@InjectMocks` annotation for that instance, then there is no error, but no caching is done (it calls `labelService.findByUuid` 2 times instead of 1).

I think I made a mistake related to the annotations in Unit Test class, but I tried many different combinations and cannot solve the problem.

So, how can I fix the problem?

**Update:** Finally I fixed the problem by using the following approach. However, I also had to update the `mockito-core` version from `3.3.3` to `3.7.0` as shown below. Otherwise I was getting "*java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/AutoCloseable;*" error.

***pom.xml:***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

***CachingTest:***

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CachingTest {

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private LabelServiceImpl labelService;
        
    @MockBean
    private LabelRepository labelRepository;

    @Test
    public void givenRedisCaching_whenFindUuid_thenReturnFromCache() {
        //code omitted 
        
        LabelDTO labelFromDb = labelService.findByUuid(uuid);
        LabelDTO labelFromCache = labelService.findByUuid(uuid);
        verify(labelRepository, times(1)).findByUuid(uuid);
        assertEquals(labelFromDb, labelFromCache);              
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again, instead rephrase or clarify the other question you asked on this. As I stated in the other one your test doesn't make sense, most of the annotations are useless and you are expecting that a mockito mock without adding spring capabilities to your test will test spring capabilities. That is ofcourse not going to happen. Autowire `LabelService` not the impl, ditch all annotations and just add `@SpringBootTest` and replace `@Mock` with `@MockBean`. And I recall giving the same answer/comment on another of your questions (which appears to be deleted).

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I juts use `@SpringBootTest` annotation, I get "*java.lang.NullPointerException*" for `labelService` (I also changed it to interface -> `LabelService`).

Comment: On the other hand, if I add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` besides `@SpringBootTest`, then I get *"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'demoCache' for Builder[public java.util.List com.mycompany.service.impl.LabelServiceImpl.findByUuid(UUID)] caches=[demoCache] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'"* error. **BUT** I think we are so close to the solution, because it looks for cache, but cannot find with that name.

Comment: I also tried by adding `@EnableCaching` annotation on my test class, but still the same problem.

Comment: If you are using junit4 (i assumed 5) you need additionally the `@RunWith`. You need to configure your cachemanager to create that cache (apparently the one you are using doesn't support creating those on the fly).

Comment: We use JUnit5, but I also tried with `@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )`, nothing has changed. So, I think the problem is not finding the named cache. Any idea?

Comment: Do I need to implement a CacheConfig? Or do I need to use `@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = { CacheAutoConfiguration.class, RedisAutoConfiguration.class})` ?

Comment: No you need to properly configure your cache manager which you havent'. Trying to again import the cache config will not solve a thing.

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-caching-2/src/main/java/com/baeldung/caching/redis/CacheConfig.java) would be ok? I use it

Comment: I used `CacheConfig` as mentioned on that link, but still the same error: *"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'demoCache' for Builder[public java.util.List com.mycompany.service.impl.LabelServiceImpl.findByUuid(UUID)] caches=[demoCache] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'"*

Comment: And why shouldn't it throw an error. Have you actually **read** the error? The name of the missing cache is in there (`demoCache`), now if you compare that with your cache configuration you should quite clearly see that `demoCache` isn't one of the caches being pre-configured.

Comment: No, I configured it with that name. The problem is not related to that. On  the other hand, I am wondering if you have ever been make a caching test or could make an example usage and post here as answer. As far as I see, people in SO post what they would like to explain instead of posting comments with lots of missing parts. That take too much time both you and PO. thanks in advance...

Comment: I give up and for some reason you try to offend people? The error is clear imho and you r config isn't what you think it is (or not loaded to whatever reason on load of annotations you put on your test).

Comment: I think I am confused with mocking service and cacheConfig. First of all, I am not sure if I need to mock cacheConfig and how to use it. That's why I ask you to post an example, because explaining with code instead of comments always useful.

Comment: My first comment was the answer you needed. You are messing around with too many annotations, configurations and try to outsmart mocking, Spring, Spring Boot and testing. Also from your question it isn't clear **where** your caching is done, the repo or the service (it should be the latter). enabling caching should be on a configuration not a component like you have now.

Comment: That's true. On the other hand, I make caching in the service, not the repo. Another issue I was confused after reading another [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-testing-cacheable) tutorial is, can I implement **Unit Test** for caching (or can I just Integration test). Can I?

Comment: Another issue is that, I have tried all of your suggestion but it was not working. I think maybe I need a proper Unit Test example of Cache testing for Spring. I have a look at, but most of them missed parts and for a beginner, I have difficulties for adapting that examples to my tests. Any suggestion or example code?

Comment: There is no caching in your service. Also the link you provide is an integration test **not** unit test. If you have the caching as in that you cannot mock your repository as that contains the caching. Finally your service code doesn't make sense (the implementation) you are calling the same method on the repo with different results, why call it twice? All the information is there and if you implemented caching in the proper way it should work, if it doesn't work there is something you aren't showing that fails to make it work, but that information is lacking.

Comment: Do you mean that I can test caching via Integration test? Or can I also use Unit Test for that? Which one would you suggest?

Comment: You cannot test using a unit test, as caching requires AOP, which requires a context, thus an integration test.

Comment: What about my update? It is working now and I think it is ok to test caching via **Unit Test** as well as Integration Test. Any comment regarding to the updated code? Is that ok, or do you have any suggestion related to that?

Comment: That isn't a unit test that is an integration test (also the extend with is useless here, the `@INjectMocks` doesn't work as as there are no mocks (or something mst have changed. ). an `@SpringBootTest` is an integration test **not** a unit test. It starts the whole application and you aren't testing a unit in isolation (the definition of a unit test).,

Comment: **BUT** if I remove the parts that you mentioned except from `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, it does not work.

Comment: The combinatin simply doesn't make sense. `@Autowired` with `@InjectMocks` is useless, you either autowire something or you inject mocks with mockito not both. The `@MockBean` is a spring annotation not a mockito annotation (that should be `@Mock`). So the combination simply doesn't make sense. So with this you should either endup with an integration test with `@SpringBootTest` and have spring boot do the mocking with `@MockBean` or an error because there are no mocks in your service... Or your code is totally different that what you have shown here.

Answer (score 3):

Mockito does not simulate your springt boot application. It just mocks the annotated objects and injects your mock objects into your labelService.

On the other hand to test a spring boot application @Autowired is not enough.

You have to build a Spring Boot Integration Test.
To do this annotate your Test with @SpringBootTest.
This initializes a real Application Context.

try to autowire, LabelService

```
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class LabelService
{
    public String getLabel()
    {
        return "Test Label " + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

package com.demo;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class CachingTest
{
    @Autowired
    private LabelService labelService;

    @Test
    public void testLabelService()
    {
        assertNotNull(labelService);
    }
}
```

this works

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I also tried `@SpringBootTest`, but `labelService` is null (I annotated it via `@Autowired`. ANy idea?

Comment: try to autowire, LabelService

Comment: I added an example in my answer

Comment: What about my update? It is working now and I think it is ok to test caching via **Unit Test** as well as Integration Test. Any comment regarding to the updated code? Is that ok, or do you have any suggestion related to that?

Comment: @Robert Please check my answer in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838320/cacheable-not-working-still-calling-the-caching-method/63841693?noredirect=1#comment119262822_63841693).